# Change parent's required JS component type in child component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs

I want to extend the JS component: `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default.js`.
I need to have a custom version of this component which uses an instance of `MyCompany_CustomCheckout/js/action/place-order` instead of `Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order` for **`placeOrderAction`**.
How can I do this?
Thanks
............................
The code for the original `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default.js` is:

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        ...
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        $,
        Component,
        placeOrderAction,
        ...
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            ... doing something with 'placeOrderAction' ...
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want override the functionality sort of like rewrite in backend, you can achieve it with following code in your `requirejs`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
         '*': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': 'MyCompany_CustomCheckout/js/action/place-order',
         }
    }
};
```

But best practice would be to use mixin, where you extend instead of overwrite the original functionality. Also in `requirejs`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'My_Module/js/action/place-order-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In both scenarios your code will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only need to override it for one of my components, but need to keep the rest of components as before. Doesn't your solution override it for all of the JS Components?

Comment: Ok, well normally then i would replace the instantiation of the script i'm replacing with `<script type="text/x-magento-init" />` inside the phtml-template, but checkout module is a different animal :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer though!